# Remove some bbcodes from code

Tags: c#, html, .net, bbcode

I am facing a problem. I am using a bbcode parser to HTML and when I try to parse it I have some problem when I have tags that is not in my set of parser.

For example:
My parser permit just `[b]`, `[center]` and `[i]` tags.
If I try to parse `[u]` or `[color={anyColor}]` tags it returns me an exception.

I would like to remove any other tag not permited.

First I thought about not permitting it on my textarea, but, when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd> to fill the textarea it fills with those tags and I notice it when the data is already on my database.

What I thought:

1. User enter the string with wrong tags
2. **I call any method to remove not permitted tags  (here is my problem)**
3. save data on my database

Can anyone help me with it? Or suggest me something else?

Comment: Did you write your parser yourself? What exception does it return?

Comment: No, I did not write it by myself. I use code kicker bbcode. Unfortunately I am not with my code right now so I can't tell you what exception is thrown, but if I find a way to remove not permited tags before parsing, it would be great for me. [link]https://bbcode.codeplex.com/

Comment: The excpetion thrown is: **CodeKicker.BBCode.BBCodeParsingException: The tag size does not exists**  SIZE is a not supported tag for my app.

Comment: In case you haven't double check your BBCode to make sure its valid. Could you also provide some code when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look into the parser src found on the link you provided, it seems that if it runs into a tag that it does not know(meaning not in the list of tags provided during instantiation) it errors out(in some manner).

As it stands it looks like you have a few options:

1. Change your `ErrorMode` to `ErrorFree`.

   - this will no longer produce any exceptions and instead treat `Unknown tags` as text.
2. Go with your original Idea and restrict the input on the front end.
3. If you can, instead of going straight to HTML, add all possible tags to the parser, check to see if you can get a c# object out of the parser and eliminate the unwanted tags before outputting to html.
4. Or on the downswing of things after html is produced prohibit the use of the generated HTML tags.
5. Send the authors of the parser an email/(if you know german) a ticket/issue on codeplex and ask them to add support for striping unwanted tags.
6. Or if you want since you have the src add functionality to strip unwanted tags, yourself

   - This shouldn't be too hard I think, follow the pattern they have for the current `Tags` list in `BBCodeParser.cs` and make an `TagsToIgnore` list and just add a check before the rest of the parsing of a tag just to strip/ continue on to the next token.

**EDIT:**
You may be able to make the parser interpret the tags to display nothing. where you init the bbCodeParser.

```
 var parser = new BBCodeParser(new[]
            {
                // keep these tags 
                new BBTag("b", "<b>", "</b>"), 
                new BBTag("i", "<span style=\"font-style:italic;\">", "</span>"), 
                new BBTag("u", "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">", "</span>"),
                // remove these (or at least there markup) 
                new BBTag("code", "", ""), 
                new BBTag("img", "", ""), 

            });
```

Comment: I still think that I will go with number 2 (Go with my original idea). But, Can anyone help me with the method to restrict it?

Comment: you could write a simple pre-parser that did just that strip any unknown/unwanted tags and there content.

Comment: I have already tried it. Didn't work. I have got what I wanted, but using regularExpression for some unwanted tags. The problem is: If any other unwanted tag which is not at my RegEx it will throw the same error. So I will have to maintenance this method forever (or at least until noone enter unwanted tag anymore).

Comment: Btw, I have marked your answer as response. It helped me. Thanks for the help.  :D